# jQuery - Remove ID not working

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to make it so when you click on an element it will remove all elements with that ID (that have the correct onclick)

```js
function reply_click(clicked_id)
{
 $("#" + clicked_id).remove();
 $(clicked_id).remove();
    alert(clicked_id + "Removed");
}
```

```html
<span id="relate1" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">Some text to remove 1</span>
Some info to keep
<span id="relate1" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">Some text to remove 1</span>
Some info to keep
<span id="relate2" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">Some text to remove 2</span>
```

I tried with the ("#" + clicked_id) and (clicked_id), just in case I was doing something wrong.

The idea is that if someone clicks the span with the id "relate1" all of the relate1 id's will be removed. However, when you press "relate2" everything else should stay.

Comment: IDs **must** be unique.

Comment: Use class instead of id.

Comment: So if I was to do "$("#" + clicked_id + "a").remove();" for example, and have id="relate1" and id="relate1a", then that should work (when you press on relate1?

Comment: @AtheistP3ace - yes, correct. I saw that as a space a.

Answer (score 0):

To remove the spam with id (of course the id must be unique):

```js
function reply_click(clicked_id)
{
  $("span[id='" + clicked_id + "']").remove();
  // $('span[class*="' + clicked_id + '"]').remove(); // to remove by class
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="relate1" class="relate1" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">Some text to remove 1</span>
Some info to keep
<span id="relate2" class="relate2" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">Some text to remove 1</span>
Some info to keep
<span id="relate3" class="relate3" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">Some text to remove 2</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not use same ID for multiple elements as its an uniuq attribute. You can use class attribute instead ID. And you can delete node by $('.'+className).remove();

Answer (score 0):

`id` must be unique. You can do this without using `id` like following.

```js
function reply_click(clicked_id)
{
    $(clicked_id).remove();
    alert(clicked_id.id + " Removed");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span id="relate1" onclick="reply_click(this)">Some text to remove 1</span>
Some info to keep
<span id="relate2" onclick="reply_click(this)">Some text to remove 1</span>
Some info to keep
<span id="relate3" onclick="reply_click(this)">Some text to remove 2</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

as All answers and comments said Ids must be unique

you can simply use

```
function reply_click(clicked_Element)
{
    clicked_Element.remove();
    alert("clicked_Element Removed");
}
```

and in html

```
<span id="relate1" onClick="reply_click(this)">Some text to remove 1</span>
Some info to keep
<span id="relate1" onClick="reply_click(this)">Some text to remove 1</span>
Some info to keep
<span id="relate2" onClick="reply_click(this)">Some text to remove 2</span>
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/betsdm3z/3/)

> Note: if you need to get any data from element you will remove .. just
>   get data before remove it not after remove

like this

```
function reply_click(clicked_Element)
    {
        var gettextBeforeRemove = clicked_Element.text();
        clicked_Element.remove();
        alert(gettextBeforeRemove +" Removed");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
function reply_click(clicked_id)
{
    $('.'+clicked_id).remove();
    alert(clicked_id + "Removed");
}
```

and html

```
   <span class="relate1" id="relate1" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">Some text to remove 1</span>
Some info to keep
  <span class="relate1" id="relate1" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">Some    text to remove 1</span>
  Some info to keep
 <span class="relate2" id="relate2" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">Some   text to remove 2</span>
```